# Deploying Symfony 3 on AWS EB

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, symfony

I have a PHP Project using Symfony 3 and I need to deploy it on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. All I tried so far hasn't worked. I can run the project locally but it doesn't work when deployed. This is what I've done so far:

- Created an AWS EB app
- Created an environment using PHP 7.4 (platform 3.5.6), and running on Apache
- Added a couple .ebextensions files to my project to make the server install and run yarn
- Uploaded a zip with all my project files (except vendor and node_modules)

When I open the site URL, I always get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. I tried setting my root to "/web", "/app" and "/" in AWS. I also tried modifying the php.config files to add Directory blocks with "AllowOverride All" (that solved Internal Server Errors), but I still can't access the website.

If I connect to the EC2 instance and run this: `curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1`

I get this: `The document has moved <a href="https://127.0.0.1/web/">here</a>`

However if I run this: `curl -X GET https://127.0.0.1/web`

I get this: `Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 443 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server`

Am I missing a step?

Comment: Does security group attached to the EC2 allow the HTTP requests? Are you able to ssh into the instance?

Comment: @ArpitJain The security group allows HTTP, HTTPS and SSH to all addresses (0.0.0.0/0). If I remove the "AllowOverride All" lines from Apache config files, I get Internal Server Error, so the server seems to be accessible from outside. Also, I can connect to the instance using the AWS Console UI, however I can't connect to it using Putty. I generated an SSH key, loaded it into Putty and tried to connect, but it always says that the server refused my key.